# MS Access: Custom reports generation

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2007, reporting

I have two tables in an MS Access database as shown below.

**Employee table:**

[image]

**Salary table:**

[image]

I have created a query for the summary of salaries for each employee, to be shown as Year based.

**Query:**

```
SELECT Employee.EmployeeID, Employee.Name, Salary.AnnualYear, 
Salary.MinSalary, Salary.Salary, Salary.MaxSalary
FROM Employee INNER JOIN Salary ON Employee.EmployeeID=Salary.EmployeeID;
```

**Query result:**

[image]

**What I want to achieve is,**

To create a Report to show the details as Year based.

**Report achieved so-far:**

[image]

**expected report:**

[image]

Will Report wizard be able to help me to achieve the expected report?

Or Do I have to do any VBA programming?

[MS Access file](http://www.sendspace.com/file/2ggsu5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Pivot table. You can take your existing query and switch to PivotTable View (open the query, right click on the tab and select PivotTable View). This results in something that looks like:
[image: Graphic of Pivot Table]

As requested. I have saved that in your file.
Find it [here.](https://app.box.com/s/y4ucj2e6pm88xe448qnk)

Answer (score 0):

Report wizard should be able to achieve that report.

Comment: Do I need to write any special query? (or) play with Grouping & Sorting? Can you please give a lead?

Comment: You can refer to this page for an overview. [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/introduction-to-reports-HA010343725.aspx)

Comment: I have tried to achieve it with report wizard & layout view. But I am unable to get the result. Could you please help? http://www.sendspace.com/file/2ggsu5

Comment: I will revert back to you soon.